# Trying to install xlwings on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Hello I amtrying to install xlwings on google colab . I have used the following line of code :

```
! pip install xlwings
```

But I have gor the follwoing error :

> Collecting xlwings   Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/c7/c21d0729ee5d62fc28fa27d3c3c007604c28c51197e458e73a1fbb800960/xlwings-0.21.4.tar.gz
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py
> egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
> So how to install the package ?

Comment: Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

xlwings requires an installation of Excel and therefore only works on Windows and macOS. Unfortunately, this means you cannot use xlwings with Colab. See  [xlwings docs](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/installation.html)